# How to detect which condition is false in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
select * from table where rep > 20 and timestamp > now() - 300;
```

As you see, there is two condition:

- `rep > 20`
- `timestamp > now() - 300`

Now I need to know, when the result of `select` is `0`, which condition breaks the query, I need to it for managing the errors. I want to show to the user, why he can not give a vote ... I need to the **reason**. So, there is any suggestion ?

Comment: You need two `sql query` to answer your two questions.

Comment: So it is not possible to I control the errors in the one query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, because it doesn't make sense.

Maybe you have plenty of rows with `rep > 20`  and maybe you have plenty of rows with `timestamp > now() - 300`, but you don't have any row that have **both** `rep > 20`  and `timestamp > now() - 300`. Therefore there is no "which condition breaks the query", it's the logical combination of both conditions that breaks the query.

If you need to debug a query (for you, as a dev), the typical process is to:

1. Run the query with only one `where` clause
2. Add another `where` clause, run the query again
3. Repeat until the result becomes zero. Then you know the last `where` clause added made the query returns zero. But again, the last `where` clause in itself might be perfectly valid - just not when used in combination with the others.